# Room TypeConverter и поиск в строке таблицы

Tags: android, room

Пожалуйста, подскажите, уже сил нет, не понимаю что делаю не так.

Есть конвертер:

```
public class MapConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    public String getStringFromMap(Map<Integer, String> map) {
        if(map!= null) {
            StringBuilder mapAsString = new StringBuilder();
            for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
                mapAsString.append(key + "=" + map.get(key) + ",");
            }
            return mapAsString.toString();
        } else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public Map<Integer, String> getMapFromString(String s) {
        Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        String[] pairs = s.split(","); // 1 элемент -  0=Элемент 0
        for (int i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
            String pair = pairs[i];
            String[] keyValue = pair.split("=");
            myMap.put(Integer.parseInt(keyValue[0]), keyValue[1]);
        }
        return myMap; 

    }
}
```

Класс объекта:

```
@Entity(tableName = "contacts")
public class Contact {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String group;
    private String subgroup;
    private String description;
    private int priority;
    @TypeConverters(MapConverter.class)
    private Map<Integer, String> mapOfGroup;
    @TypeConverters(MapConverter.class)
    private Map<Integer, String> mapOfSubGroup;
```

Метод DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE mapOfGroup LIKE '%' || :nameGroup || '%' ")
Flowable<List<Contact>> getAllContactsOfGroup(String nameGroup);
```

Ничего не возвращает. как я только не пробовал. Пробовал и так `LIKE :nameGroup || '%'`
При этом, в таблицу объект добавляется:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя пока в конвертере не добавил строчку в метод `getStringFromMap`:

```
 } else{
            return null;
        }
```

данные не добавлялись и выдавало ошибку.
При этом по логам вижу такую строчку при попытке получить данные:

```
2021-11-10 23:05:53.782 21564-21564/com.example.contacts D/Throwable get Contacts of Group: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Заранее спасибо!

UPDATE:
нашел ошибку при добавлении в конвертере, переделал, но все равно не могу получить данные
Новый конвертер:

```
 @TypeConverter
public String getStringFromMap(Map<Integer, String> map) {
    StringBuilder mapAsString = new StringBuilder();
    int sizeMap = map.size()-1;
    int counter = 0;
    for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
        if(counter == sizeMap){
            mapAsString.append(key + "=" + map.get(key));
        } else {
            mapAsString.append(key + "=" + map.get(key) + ",");
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return mapAsString.toString();
}
```

ошибка приходит при получении:

```
D/Throwable get Contacts of Group: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Comment: Не `||`, а `or`

Comment: Сделал `@Query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE mapOfGroup LIKE   '%' or :nameGroup or '%' ")` все равно не находит и возвращает ошибку: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: UPDATE: выяснил, оказывается после исправления конвертера не добавляются объекты в БД. При добавлении возвращает: `Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.Map.size()' on a null object reference`  на строке: `int sizeMap = map.size()-1;` т.е. что-то с конвертером. Что не так?

Comment: выяснил, что конвертер вызывается два раза. Первый раз map есть, все проходит нормально, второй раз вызывается, map=null. не пойму почему второй раз вызывается

Comment: сорри, не разглядел, это у вас конкатенация. все верно было.

Answer (score 0):

В общем решено:
Проблема была в том, что в классе `Contact` у второго поля `private Map<Integer, String> mapOfSubGroup;` так же был указан `@TypeConverters` но при этом, в это поле не передавался `Map`.
Поэтому конвертер вызывался два раза - первый раз отрабатывал нормально, а на этом поле выкидывал ошибку, что `Map null`

Сам Query запрос работает и так: `'%' || :nameGroup || '%'` и так `'%' or :nameGroup or '%' ")`